# API URL requires "/api/api/" after being published

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I've got an API app up and running on my localhost. It works great at en endpoint such as:

```
http://localhost:26307/api/ModelName/12345
```

However, after deploying to the Test server, the same url needs to be:

```
http://v10test.mydomain.com/api/api/ModelName/12345
```

I'm trying to get rid of the double /api/.

I adjusted my routes **FROM THIS** (for example):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}"
);
```

**TO THIS**.....

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route2",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{organizationSys}"
);
```

**NOTE: I REMOVED "api/" FROM THE ROUTES.**

But that seemed to have no effect. In IIS, the api's are set up as an Application within the domain:

[image]

I'm probbaly overlooking something obvious, but I'm just not sure what. How do I get rid of that double `/api/`?

Comment: You're deploying to the virtual 'api' app and then the route takes effect beyond that.

Comment: Sure, so then without having `api/` in the route, where is the need to have `api/` in the url coming from?

Comment: I think your second configuration should be right. After you deploy it you might have to recycle/restart the api app. Maybe the config is still in memory.

Comment: yeah that's what I am thinking too. But I can't seem to clear it.  I've tried everything to clear the cache, but nothing seems to work.  That's what made me think I am missing something. I'll keep trying.

Comment: To verify, try creating a new app in iis and call it api2, then deploy with the route that doesn't have api in it to verify.

Comment: @Hoots, good idea.  I did that, and it only works at: http://v10test.eioboard.com/api2/api/AccessIntegrationSettings/12345

Comment: Check that your controller doesn't override the path with its own Route attribute

Comment: AH - HA!! nailed it Hoots.  If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as such.  (I knew it was something obvious.)

Comment: Will do and I'll put a proper explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to specify routes to a controllers actions, and the order of precedence matters.

Firstly, it can be done from a general configuration, e.g. as you've done it...

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route2",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{organizationSys}"
);
```

However this can be overridden by specifying a Route attribute on the controller or by specifying the route in the verb attribute. For example in the code below...

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api")]  // url... /api
    [Route("/api/test")] // url... /api/test
    [Route("testalso")] // url... /api/test/get/testalso
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Alive";
    }

    [HttpGet("/api/echo/{id}")] // url... /api/echo/{id}
    public string Echo(string id)
    {
        return $"Get Echo: {id}";
    }

    [HttpPost("{id}")]  // url... /api/test/postit/{id}
    public string PostIt(string id)
    {
        return $"Thanks for {id}";
    }
}
```

The declaration on the controller specifies a default for all methods within the controller and any methods that specify attributes can either override the controller by starting the route with a '/' or append to the controller's route. See the comments next to each attribute above for examples.

Beyond that the routes will be relative to the base application hosted within iis in your case which starts at...

```
http://v10test.mydomain.com/api/
```

Hope that's enough information for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the way it is deployed in IIS. For IIS your application is at address

`http://v10test.mydomain.com/api/`

And after that comes all the controllers and etc. If you deploy it to (for example)

`http://v10test.mydomain.com/myapp/`

the calls will work like

`http://v10test.mydomain.com/myapp/api/ModelName/12345`

**EDIT**

Also - check the routes of your controllers or methods inside the controllers. This is the other place where the route may be modified/extended.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  But I thought that removing the `api/` from the routes would also remove the need to have `api/` in the url at all.

Comment: Removing it from the routes will end up with only one `/api/` because of the virtual directory, that it is deployed to

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my OP, but I DID remove it from the route, and it STILL requires the double /api/api/

Comment: And this is the only route that you currently have?

Comment: No, it's just an example. But I removed "api/" from all of them.

Comment: And one more thing (I guess that you've tried but I need to ask) - did you redeploy, recycle IIS etc.

Comment: Yes :) but a fair question

Comment: hmm... what about the controllers themselves - do they have some routes, because this is the other place, where you can specify some route that can add to the url?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem!  Hoots already figured that out too (see the comments under the OP). But, maybe update your answer to reflect that?